# Looking for guidance on CSS code for class

Tags: html, css

I'm doing an assignment in my class with HTML and CSS. I'm having trouble getting the navigation for phone and tablet views to look like the attached image. I'm assuming this could be resolved toward the bottom of the CSS code? Also, my page looks very wide compared to the photos in all views. I'm very much a novice at this if it isn't obvious.

```css
body {
  background-color: #b8dbed;
  font-family: Arial;
}

header {
  background-color: #000033;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 120px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1.5em;
  font-size: 120%;
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-family: Georgia;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: 0.25em;
}

h2 {
  color: #3399cc;
  font-family: Georgia;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #cccccc;
}

h3 {
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: #000033;
}

dt {
  color: #000033;
}

.resort {
  color: #5c7fa3;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

main ul {
  list-style-image: url(marker.gif);
}

footer {
  font-size: 75%;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 190px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

#contact {
  font-size: 90%;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  min-width: 2048px;
  background: #90c7e3;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333333;
  border: 1px solid #000033;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #90c7e3);
}

main {
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin-left: 190px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#homehero {
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(coast2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin-left: 190px;
}

#trailhero {
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(trail.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin-left: 190px;
}

#yurthero {
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(yurt.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin-left: 190px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a:link {
  color: #5c7fa3;
}

a:visited {
  color: #344873;
}

a:hover {
  color: #a52a2a;
}

header,
main,
nav,
footer,
figure,
figcaption,
aside,
section,
article {
  display: block;
}

#mobile {
  display: none;
}

#desktop {
  display: inline;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 64em) {
  body {
    background: #ffffff;
  }
  #wrapper {
    min-width: 0;
    width: auto;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
  }
  header {
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding-left: 0;
    height: auto;
  }
  h1 {
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  }
  main {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  nav {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
  nav li {
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 0.25em;
    padding-bottom: 0.25em;
    padding-left: 0.75em;
    padding-right: 0.75em;
  }
  #homehero {
    margin-left: 0;
    height: 200px;
  }
  #yurthero {
    margin-left: 0;
    height: 200px;
  }
  #trailhero {
    margin-left: 0;
    height: 200px;
  }
  footer {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 37.5em) {
  main {
    padding-top: 0.1em;
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    font-size: 90%;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  nav {
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #330000;
  }
  nav a {
    display: block;
  }
  #homehero {
    background-image: none;
    height: 0;
  }
  #yurthero {
    background-image: none;
    height: 0;
  }
  #trailhero {
    background-image: none;
    height: 0;
  }
  #mobile {
    display: inline;
  }
  #desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1> Pacific Trails Resort </h1>
</header>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a> <a href="yurts.html">Yurts</a> <a href="activities.html">Activities</a> <a href="reservations.html">Reservations</a>
  </ul>

</nav>
<div id="homehero">

</div>
<main>
  <h2>Enjoy Nature in Luxury</h2>
  <p> <span class="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span> offers a special lodging experience on the California North Coast with panoramic views of the Pacific Ocean. Your stay at Pacific Trails Resort includes a sumptuously appointed private yurt and a cooked-to-order
    breakfast each morning.</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Unwind in the heated outdoor pool and whirlpool</li>

    <li>Explore the coast on your own or join our guided tours</li>

    <li>Relax in our lodge while enjoying complimentary appetizers and beverages</li>

    <li>Savor nightly fine dining with an ocean view</li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <div id="contact">
    <span class="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span> <br> 12010 Pacific Trails Road <br> Zephyr, CA 95555 <br>

    <br>

    <a id="mobile" href="tel:888-555-5555">888-555-5555</a> <br>
    <span id="desktop">888-555-5555</span>

    <br>

  </div>
</main>

<footer>
  Copyright © 2018 Pacific Trails Resort<br>
  <a href="mailto:e.sween12@gmail.com">e.sween12@gmail.com</a>
</footer>
</div>
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

[image: this is how the page should look in all views]

Comment: Do you mean the gradient or spacing? What is the specific problem in the navigation?

Comment: read about `media queries` then read about difference between `css pixel` and `hardware pixel`. Then you should know how this is done: https://mediag.com/blog/popular-screen-resolutions-designing-for-all/

Comment: can you better explain the problem you are having.  You are certainly on the right path with media queries but I wouldn't use em's as the base unit may change.  Use pixels (px) instead.  Google media query for mobile, tablets and pc's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. I found a few typos in your HTML code like the `<header>` not having an opening tag, along with semantic issues such as not using `<li>` elements in your unordered lists. After updating the HTML, all that was left was to provide a background color for the containers which hold the nav menu items at mobile and tablet viewport widths (ie the two media queries). I added a stock photo to the `background-image` for demonstration.

Lastly, updating your media queries to use `px` values instead of `em`. As @DCR mentioned, the `em` base value may change which in turn would cause your media queries to take affect at varying widths determined by the base value. Everything seems to match the desired output in the images you've included.

If you would like the page content to not exceed a certain viewport width, just specify [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width) on the `<body>` and center it on the page with `margin: 0 auto` which creates 0 top/bottom margin and "auto" sized left/right margins to center the content. I also added a `border` and `box-shadow` to the `body` at "desktop size" so it matches your desired output.

```css
body {
  background-color: #b8dbed;
  font-family: Arial;
  max-width: 100ch; /* vary this */
  margin: 0 auto 1rem auto;
  border: .1rem solid #333;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px 0px #222;
}

header {
  background-color: #000033;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 120px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1.5em;
  font-size: 120%;
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-family: Georgia;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: 0.25em;
}

h2 {
  color: #3399cc;
  font-family: Georgia;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #cccccc;
}

h3 {
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: #000033;
}

dt {
  color: #000033;
}

.resort {
  color: #5c7fa3;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

main ul {
  list-style-image: url(marker.gif);
}

footer {
  font-size: 75%;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 190px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

#contact {
  font-size: 90%;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  min-width: 2048px;
  background: #90c7e3;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333333;
  border: 1px solid #000033;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #90c7e3);
}

main {
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin-left: 190px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#homehero {
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(https://www.visitcalifornia.com/sites/visitcalifornia.com/files/NC_DuncansCove_Seeff_1280x642_sized_downsized.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin-left: 190px;
}

#trailhero {
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(trail.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin-left: 190px;
}

#yurthero {
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(yurt.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin-left: 190px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a:link {
  color: #5c7fa3;
}

a:visited {
  color: #344873;
}

a:hover {
  color: #a52a2a;
}

header,
main,
nav,
footer,
figure,
figcaption,
aside,
section,
article {
  display: block;
}

#mobile {
  display: none;
}

#desktop {
  display: inline;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    background: #ffffff;
    max-width: none;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  #wrapper {
    min-width: 0;
    width: auto;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
  }
  header {
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding-left: 0;
    height: auto;
  }
  h1 {
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  }
  main {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  nav {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background: rgba(213, 244, 250, .4);
  }
  nav li {
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 0.25em;
    padding-bottom: 0.25em;
    padding-left: 0.75em;
    padding-right: 0.75em;
  }
  #homehero {
    margin-left: 0;
    height: 200px;
  }
  #yurthero {
    margin-left: 0;
    height: 200px;
  }
  #trailhero {
    margin-left: 0;
    height: 200px;
  }
  footer {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
  }
  main {
    padding-top: 0.1em;
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    font-size: 90%;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  nav {
    padding: 0;
    background: rgba(213, 244, 250, .4);
  }
  nav li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #330000;
  }
  nav a {
    display: block;
  }
  #homehero {
    background-image: none;
    height: 0;
  }
  #yurthero {
    background-image: none;
    height: 0;
  }
  #trailhero {
    background-image: none;
    height: 0;
  }
  #mobile {
    display: inline;
  }
  #desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
<h1> Pacific Trails Resort </h1>
</header>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a> 
    <li><a href="yurts.html">Yurts</a></li>
    <li><a href="activities.html">Activities</a></li>
    <li><a href="reservations.html">Reservations</a></li>
  </ul>

</nav>
<div id="homehero">

</div>
<main>
  <h2>Enjoy Nature in Luxury</h2>
  <p> <span class="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span> offers a special lodging experience on the California North Coast with panoramic views of the Pacific Ocean. Your stay at Pacific Trails Resort includes a sumptuously appointed private yurt and a cooked-to-order
    breakfast each morning.</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Unwind in the heated outdoor pool and whirlpool</li>

    <li>Explore the coast on your own or join our guided tours</li>

    <li>Relax in our lodge while enjoying complimentary appetizers and beverages</li>

    <li>Savor nightly fine dining with an ocean view</li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <div id="contact">
    <span class="resort">Pacific Trails Resort</span> <br> 12010 Pacific Trails Road <br> Zephyr, CA 95555 <br>

    <br>

    <a id="mobile" href="tel:888-555-5555">888-555-5555</a> <br>
    <span id="desktop">888-555-5555</span>

    <br>

  </div>
</main>

<footer>
  Copyright © 2018 Pacific Trails Resort<br>
  <a href="mailto:e.sween12@gmail.com">e.sween12@gmail.com</a>
</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: @ElizabethSweeney Does this help solve your problem?

Comment: I don't know if you're able to help...my screen width is really wide in general for all views...do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: @ElizabethSweeney Your welcome! Feel free to mark my answer as accepted. To handle the content's max width, you can specify a max-width. Have a look at my updated post.

Comment: I had a typo for the min-width in the wrapper that did the trick. thanks so much!